# What's the best method for figuring out whether clusters occurring in data are random or are indicative of an underlying non-random behavior?

Tags: time-series, randomness

I have a dataset of the times that events happen. I noticed some clustering of events but I know that even assuming a random uniform distribution some amount clustering will inevitably occur. How do I test whether the clustering I see is random or non-random?

Edit:
Example data:

```
11 Jan 2017 18:45:37
11 Jan 2017 19:05:52
11 Jan 2017 19:18:15
11 Jan 2017 20:08:10
```

Comment: We're going to need more information about your situation. You've added the `[time-series]` tag, but I can't tell if you really have time series data. You say you have "times that events happen", are you talking about something like the hour of the day when a purchase is made on a website, or the length of time between an initial event & a follow-up event? Can you post your data? Do you have covariates? Etc.

Comment: Edited with some example data. It's literally just date-times. No other factors; all events are of the same type (no "initial" or "follow-up" event)

Comment: That helps some, thanks. But, what are these (ie, date-times for what)? Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals?

Comment: Would the method be different for different situations? I'm trying to figure out whether these events might not actually be random and might have an underlying cause which would be indicated by unusually high amounts of clustering

Comment: Most analyses start from a model. That requires that we have some way of thinking about what the numbers are, how they're related to each other, & how they might be generated. They aren't just arbitrary numbers. We need to know more about the situation.